# .Net core connectionstring for db2

Tags: .net-core, db2, connection-string, db2-400

With .NET classic I used to have a connectionstring like this (to connect to db2 instance) :

```
DataSource=10.10.1.1;UserID=MyUser;Password=MyPWD;LibraryList=LIB1,*USRLIBL;Naming=System;
```

But this connectionstring doesn't work anymore with .NET CORE.

I've found something like :

```
server=10.10.1.1:446;database=TheDB;user id=MyUser;password=MyPWD;
```

But I don't find anything for LibraryList. What is the equivalent ?

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195417/ibm-db2-core-connection-string-for-asp-net-core-2-1-and-microsoft-enterprise-li

Comment: it seems it's the naming=system that is not available, how to set naming system ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715889/ibm-net-data-provider-connection-string-issue-with-library-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemNaming seems to be available only via code, not in connectionstring :

```
    using (var db = new DB2Connection(ConnectionStrings))
    {
        db.SystemNaming = true;
    }
```

Ref : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/r0060653.html